# wrong output code

Tags: c++

The following code gives the wrong binary output:
The input is a HEX number and the output should be a binary number.

It always outputs:

```
0    
0    
0    
0
```

How can I change it so it outputs the right binary number?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{   

int Number;
cin >> Number;
bool Binary[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
    Binary[(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) - i] = Number & (1 << i);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
    std::cout << Binary[i] << std::endl;

system ("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with your question title?

Comment: @Joriek, edit the title so that it reflects your problem.

Comment: "wrong output" does not reflect the problem to a sufficiently descriptive degree. It should aid somebody to find this post in a web search in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating it right but printing only `sizeof(int)` bits, not all bits. In last print loop use `i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
    std::cout << Binary[i] << std::endl;
```